# ubuntu server not accepting connections from subnets

Tags: networking, server, openvpn, routing, subnet

Yesterday I rebooted our kvm server (added more rams) and now it will not accept connections from our VPN subnet. The VPN is working just fine as we can connect to any other resource on the network with it, we can even ssh into other servers and then ssh to the kvm server just fine.

I am assuming it's a routing issue on the kvm server itself, but I am also no good at networking as a whole so I could be off. So here is what I see on our kvm server right now.

```
Kernel IP routing table

Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

0.0.0.0         10.0.1.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1

10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 eno1

192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0



colomboj@llamaU:/etc/network$ sudo ip route add default via 10.0.1.1
RTNETLINK answers: File exists



colomboj@llamaU:~$ ifconfig
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:d3:c1:f9:2c:b0
          inet addr:10.0.1.26  Bcast:10.255.255.255  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a2d3:c1ff:fef9:2cb0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:463789 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:86171 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:67782472 (67.7 MB)  TX bytes:61790310 (61.7 MB)
          Interrupt:26

eno4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:d3:c1:f9:2c:b3
          inet6 addr: fe80::a2d3:c1ff:fef9:2cb3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22676675 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14416066 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:30904818494 (30.9 GB)  TX bytes:6309304520 (6.3 GB)
          Interrupt:27

kbeno4    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:d3:c1:f9:2c:b3
          inet6 addr: fe80::a2d3:c1ff:fef9:2cb3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:387211 errors:0 dropped:182 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:12 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:44493132 (44.4 MB)  TX bytes:1008 (1.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:275064 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:275064 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
          RX bytes:91186474 (91.1 MB)  TX bytes:91186474 (91.1 MB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:bd:87:0d
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:72:a6:d8
         inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe72:a6d8/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:211823 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:852803 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:96807081 (96.8 MB)  TX bytes:733415057 (733.4 MB)

vnet1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:11:5c:71
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe11:5c71/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2058089 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2186016 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:4622600708 (4.6 GB)  TX bytes:766854534 (766.8 MB)

vnet2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:6c:ce:79
           inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe6c:ce79/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9832831 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17156907 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1373470104 (1.3 GB)  TX bytes:26093755232 (26.0 GB)

vnet3     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:2c:67:4c
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe2c:674c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:2361 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:373687 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:167606 (167.6 KB)  TX bytes:56511156 (56.5 MB)

 vnet4     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:f9:58:e3
           inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fef9:58e3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:92247 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:565562 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:6333769 (6.3 MB)  TX bytes:347518136 (347.5 MB)

vnet5     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:54:00:3d:a4:3a
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fe3d:a43a/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:606896 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2258186 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:49613137 (49.6 MB)  TX bytes:2981105002 (2.9 GB)

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eno1
iface eno1 inet dhcp
auto kbeno4
iface kbeno4 inet manual
bridge_ports eno4
```

The topology of the network looks something like this
10.0.1.1 is the Router running pfsense and that is where the openVPN server is as well

10.0.2.1 is the openVPN gateway and that .2.x subnet is where our VPN clients are found

10.0.1.26 is the kvm server we can't access from the .2.x subnet

So I'm looking for a little guidance on how to get this fixed, because it's not cool having to triple hop our way to a VM to do maintenance amiright!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
route add -net 10.0.2.0 gw 10.0.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

That says that for this device to send data to the `10.0.2.0` subnet (`netmask 255.255.255.0`), it has go through the `10.0.1.1` gateway.